# Очередь с фиксированным размером и реверс итератором

Tags: java, структуры-данных

Задача кэшировать некие поступающие объекты отчетов, но в заранее заданном объеме. Что-то вроде `new ArrayBlockingQueue<Report>(100)`, но при определенных обстоятельства ради которых этот кэш и храниться, нужно проходить по этой очереди от свежих отчетов, к более старым.

Как это можно реализовать без велосипедов? Может в гуаве что-то есть такое готовое?

Comment: а какие тут велосипеды? По вашему описанию ArrayBlockingQueue уже подходит. Недостающую логику недолго унаследоваться и дописать.

Comment: [LinkedBlockingDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html)?